# I keep getting lost in to areas

Tags: objects

My pointer keeps changing into a crosshairs and I then cannot select anything on the screen. I keep getting a coloured circled when I try to select. How do I get the regular mouse pointer back??

Also. looking for the steps to group objects on the screen, examples: curves in svg.

Comment: Hi eugepejazzy, your question is a bit ambiguous and difficult to answer. If you have a separate question about grouping objects, please post that separately. As for your problem, ensure you are in the right mode; Object mode is generally default, you can change it either with the button in the upper left or by pressing Ctrl+Tab.

Answer (score 0):

You might have switched from the selector to the 3d cursor 
watch
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8AqaKD0d5v0